# Azure DevOps Server 2020 - Missing Options

Tags: azure-devops

I have DevOps 2020 Server on a test machine and I noticed I am missing options.  I am trying to go to Repos > Branches, but it's not listed in my options.

I see the following options from a training video:

[image]

But the following is what I have.  I'm missing Commits, Pushes, Branches, Tags, Pull Requests, and I have 2 that aren't the the first picture.

[image]

Is it configured incorrectly or are these the only available options now?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are using TFVC for your project. If you want to use Git, you'll need to add Git repositories.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Mann.  This project doesn't use Git.  Thank you for the tip though.

Comment: @JM1 Then what you're seeing is expected. That's what the UI for projects backed by TFVC looks like.